# SSHelper Server not reachable

Tags: file-transfer, ssh, firewall

SSHelper SSH server works very nice on my old Samsung S2. But it does not work on a newer device of my son.

I installed no firewall on the new device. Is there some restriction which does not allow running a server on the android device?

I can't reach the port `2222` and I can't get the device to answer ping requests.

For me SSHelper is the most simple way to transfer files between my linux desktop and the mobile phone.

Comment: Which "newer device" and Android version are you referring to?

Comment: @Firelord the new device is a motorola moto G.

Answer (score 1):

sshelper works great on my Samsung S5.

In sshelper under the wrench icon you can increase the verbosity of the data logging mode, try increasing that and then pointing your browser to the listed 'ssh server address' and append the 'log server port number' (default :8080).  This might give you a clue as to why your having issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for the noise here. It was a very strange bug in my wifi router. Some devices were reachable, some not. After rebooting the wifi router I was able to connect to the SSHelper server on the android device again.